# Keep a subset of user details secure across multiple pages using javascript

Tags: javascript, cookies

I'm not certain it's even possible, but is there a way to keep user information secure across multiple pages while only using javascript?

I have a predefined set of details recovered from three separate API requests, initial call sends user credentials to the login_api via a POST and returns a small set of data (OAuth2 token, user birth name, etc.), the ensuing calls fire, upon success, for 2 lanes of products via GET calls, these requests return a list of products for each lane which is perceived as what this user is licensed to view.

I've not had a great deal of experience in setting up secure user authentication and remembered data across a multi-paged website so I want to ensure I am taking the proper approach.

With the functions below I can create _private variables inside of functions that utilize that data.

All *remembered* data is applied within the XHR responses to the cookie storage area, it never leaves the scope of the request function.

From that point forward all data is retrieved via cookies, used within a singular function scope, never leaving the scope of the function it is utilized in. Each time the data is required it is re-fetched from the cookies. I'm not certain how secure cookies are, I debated clearing cookies each time the data is recovered and re-applying updated values upon the function's completion, but thought it overkill.

If any piece of relevant cookie data is not present on page load they're redirected to the login page and all relevant cookie data, if present, is removed.

**Is there any way to improve retaining an OAuth2 token and handful of user details across multiple pages without leaking user information with only javascript?**

**NOTE**
This is within a rather old internal website and in keeping things familiar for the team we're using ES5 and below, it's moving away from internal use only.

```
var config = Object.create(null);
config.expire_item = 30; // minutes

function dataref() {

  // setup objects to store details in
  var output;
  output = Object.create(null);
  output.access = Object.create(null);
  output.licensed = Object.create(null);
  output.token = "_token"; 

  // apply predefined names as object values
  // cookies in this namespace holds user name
  output.fname = "_fname"; 
  // cookies in this namespace store true/false flags
  output.has_access.ces = "ces_license";
  output.has_access.ezg = "ezg_license";
  // cookies in this namespace hold pipe & comma delimited product lists
  output.licensed_for.ces = 'ces_products'; 
  output.licensed_for.ezg = 'ezg_products';
  // ...etc.

  return function () {
    // return object with predefined names for cookies
    return output;
  }();

}

function apply_userdata(fn) {
  // get predefined cookie names
  var _data = dataref();
  return function () {
    // apply function to all namespaces
    fn(_data.token);
    fn(_data.fname);
    fn(_data.access.ces);
    fn(_data.access.ezg);
    fn(_data.licensed.ces);
    fn(_data.licensed.ezg);
  }();
}

function resetCookieExpire(name) {
  // updates cookie expiration period.
  return setCookie(name, getCookie(name), option.expire_item);
}

function getUserSensativeData(name) {
  // retrieve cookie value
  return getCookie(name)
}

function deleteUserSensativeData(name) {
  // remove cookie name/value
  return deleteCookie(name);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should preface this with "I'm no auth expert either", however I have worked with several different kinds of user auth in the past on multiple projects.  There's a little bit of missing information that seems implied by what you're saying, but it appears you are either using oauth2 implicit flow or oauth2 authorization code flow. in either circumstance, in order to persist across separate page loads, you would have to use either cookies or local storage as you currently are, unless it's a single page application, in which case it sounds like it's not.
Based on how you've described this project it sounds like you're trying to sunset it, that being said, if you really feel bad about storing these client side credentials you could switch to an OIDC style flow that uses secure=true;httpOnly=true cookies that automatically get sent with each request.  That sounds like it's not an option for you.
Oauth2 is considered secure, and storing a client side credential for repeated use is not "breaking" any rules.  The reason storing a client side credential can be considered vulnerable is because of [XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)) or [CSRF](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF)) attacks

Having a Content Security Policy goes a long way too.

There are additional precautions you can take, such as having a short expire time (1 hour is pretty common) or even having the ability to manually expire access_tokens in an emergency.  Hope this helps.

Comment: I think that summed things up nicely. Also, if they opt to logout it essentially is a manual clear of their token. Their credentials are only retained within the scope of the initial xhr request, after that it's cleared and the token itself is relied on. So all should be okay. Thanks for the insight!